# SQL Server : uniqueidentifier type Inserting Before Old Rows After Reboot, How to Prevent?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, guid, uniqueidentifier

I have a SQL Server table that is using a `uniqueidentifier` as a clustered primary key. After creating the table and inserting several rows, I rebooted my server. The column uses `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` as its default value.

After reboot however, the next insert created a row with a GUID that was lower in value than those before, causing it to appear at the top of a `SELECT *` statement.

My question: is there any way to prevent shuffling (AKA preserve the ordering of rows) while using a GUID type clustered primary key?

Comment: In brief: no. Those GUID's are - at best - pseudo-sequential, and most definitely after the SQL Server service has stopped and restarted, there's no more guarantee whatsoever. GUIDs as PK are a horribly bad choice anyways - I would look into `INT IDENTITY` which is much better in terms of performance, and those values are guaranteed by SQL Server, will be ever-increasing - even after a server reboot.

Comment: And this is described here (and probably hundreds of other places, this was just the first useful search result): http://sqltrends.blogspot.com/2011/04/difference-between-newsequentialid-and.html

Comment: No order by. There is nothing to order by, since it is a list of user accounts, with nothing but usernames and oauth tokens. However, chronological order is still preferred.

Comment: A `TOP (x)` without an `ORDER BY` is pretty pointless - you're getting **what** top 10 rows?? If they're not order by something - which 10 rows do you expect to see??

Comment: @marc_s The first 10 rows inserted (the oldest 10 accounts added).

Comment: But again: unless you explicitly **specify** an `ORDER BY` - there's **no implied ordering** in a SQL Server database. You'll get back 10 arbitrary rows ....

Comment: @AaronBertrand: have you covered the fact that there's no implied ordering in SQL Server  - no order without `ORDER BY` in your blog already? If so: link? If not: that would make a good topic! Too many folks still seems to cling to the "natural order" or "order as the rows were inserted" myth ...

Comment: @marc_s I talk a little about it here: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior.aspx

Comment: @marc_s, sql server guarantees they'll increase doesn't stop some one messing with identity insert though, to say rekey the table filling any gaps left by deletes which is a regular trick. Using DateTime as Mr Bertrand suggested answered is the way to do this, make things explicit instead of relying on an implied vendor specific implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to guarantee chronological order, add a column called `CreatedDate`, set it to not allow NULLs, and set the default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Then to get the last 10 rows, you can say:

```
SELECT TOP 10 (*) FROM dbo.foo ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC;
```

This way your `TOP` makes sense. Without `ORDER BY`, as marc explained, your `TOP` is meaningless and while the results will be relatively predictable (they're not quite random, I'd prefer the term "arbitrary"), they are not going to have any reliability to be ordered in the same order they were inserted. This is true whether you use a GUID or an integer for your primary key - no guarantees.

You are never going to be able to guarantee order preservation with `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`, sorry, that's just not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says it generates a new guid guaranteed to be after the last one done since windows was started.

Put a date added column in there use that for ordering, and just use newid for your guid. Not only will it work, it will give you more info, and be completely obvious what's going on, not to mention it will make your design more portable.

Comment: And a GUID with `newid()` will even even more of a horribly bad choice for a PK .... [but that's a totally different story](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx) ....

Comment: I try to avoid it myself, too sparse to be efficient. BigInt primary key as a surrogate and Guid as a unique key for scaling across distributed data is a better way to go. That aside I wouldn't even rely on a bigint to indicate order of data, too easy to break the implied rule without realising it.